# Получаю ошибку при выводе .json файла в консоль

Tags: javascript, json

Я только сегодня начал знакомиться с .json и серверным js в принципе. По гайду из ютуба я написал код, но выдает ошибку.
Вот гайд: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7lzKar7m0g&t=492s
Вот ошибка: GEThttp://127.0.0.1:5500/favicon.ico
описание в консоли:
Состояние404
Not Found
ВерсияHTTP/1.1
Передано150 б (размер 150 б)
Политика Referrerno-referrer-when-downgrade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Магазин книг</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src = 'script.js'></script>
    <style rel = 'stylesheet' link = 'style.css'></style>

</body>
</html>
```

```
window.addEventListener('DOMcontentLoaded', () => {
    function req(){
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.open('GET', "http://localhost:3000/people")
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "appication/json; charset=utf-8")
        request.send()
        request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
            if(request.readyState == 4){
                let data = JSON.parse(request.response)
                console.log(data)
            }
            else{
                console.error('Не получилось')
            }
        })
    }
    req()
})
```

Comment: у вас 404. Т.е. страницу по указанному пути не находит. Возможно вам нужно писать путь без  `http:://`

Comment: я поискал на форумах, как я понял, то эта ошибка связана со значком сайта, я его не добавлял, потом добавил, но ошибка такая же. Я и из самого компьютера тоже брал файл с расширением .ico т.е получается без http::// так что нет

Comment: У вас точно "ошибка при выводе .json файла в консоль"? Уберите консоль-логи, будет ли ошибка? Если не будет, то задайте вопрос иначе. Потому что при выводе в консоль не может быть такой ошибки как вы описываете. Локализуйте задачу, уберите всё лишнее, тогда возможно и json будет не при чём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему просто написав

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"/>
```

в head